# Pure python library to handle raster data (not GDAL, rasterio)

Tags: python, raster

I would like to do some basic operations over some downloaded raster files  (`tiff`) and include the process in a package, but I don't want the users of my package to install `GDAL`, neither `rasterio`.

In the process I basically download every band of a multiband raster separately, and need to merge all into one single raster `tiff`. I know it can be done with the mentioned packages, but I need a pure python solution for this simple task. I was thinking in [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/download.html) but I am not sure how it will be for handling geographic information, mainly CRS.

Comment: What you describe is simple image manipulation? A raster dataset is not much different from a multidimensional array, so you can use whatever image library you prefer. CRS information is just metadata that is either stored in the header or in extra files, so shouldn't be troubled by it. If you have concerns about speed or specific tasks, more specific suggestions can be given.

Comment: How about PIL/Pillow http://pythonware.com/products/pil/?

Comment: skimage likely leans on numpy, so there goes your pure python.  I would recommend looking into freezing packages e.g. with pyinstaller so you can lean on the existing functionality of those purpose-built libraries

Comment: Thank you all. I guess all band must be in the same projection in order to use a simple image manipulation library

Comment: Neither scikit-image (written in Cython) or PIL/pillow (written in C) are pure python.  I don't know of a pure python geotiff/raster package, but if you did find one, I would bet that it has at least one or two binary dependencies (i.e numpy or libtiff).

Comment: Something of this kind is in the making, Rodrigo. It's indeed hard to avoid numpy. And so far - with what I have - users have to live with several restrictions. E.g. that all layers must have the same projection and the same extent. Reading / writing tiff can be done somehow, using the Python library tifffile from Christoph Gohlke. I just asked a question on this forum because I'm facing some restrictions with this library.

Comment: Thank you @Dobedani, I know avoiding numpy is hard, and wouldn't even make sense. I just want to avoid GDAL. Tifffile looks fine, but it's a pity it doesn't have an OS repository, like GitHub